# Wait for a function to finish in forloop

Tags: javascript

I am designing a website with deCarta maps. I need to add some overlays for a certain number of points. My code looks as follows,

```
for(var i = 0; i<NumberofPoints; i++){
    var lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3;

    //some calculations  for coordinates go here

    //create a line object
    var polyline = new deCarta.Core.Polyline({
    lineGeometry: [
        new deCarta.Core.Position(lat2, lon2),
        new deCarta.Core.Position(lat1, lon1),
        new deCarta.Core.Position(lat3, lon3)
    ],
    strokeColor: '#000088',
    strokeWidth: 2
    });

    //add to map
    shapeOverlay.addObject(polyline);   

}
```

If I add a manual delay (using `alert('plotting point number'+i);`) somewhere within the loop, I get the all points on the map. Otherwise, I get nothing! I'm guessing the call to create the line object and adding it to the map isn't finished before iterating over the loop.

So my question is, how do I ensure that the call to create the line object and add to the map is finished before going over to the next point in the loop?

Sorry if the question isn't well worded. It's my first time posting here (or my first time using JavaScript for that matter!) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It won't do the next iteration until its completed the stuff in the `{}` so i'm a little confused what you mean by waiting till the next loop ?

Comment: I'm only guessing that the calls to create line and add it the map are not completed before the next iteration. I could be wrong about this though. The trouble I'm having is, if I stop each iteration with an `alert` statement, the map is populated with lines, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Well if none show my guess is after your drawing the lines, your clearing the canvas some where? But Alert `pauses` the code thus stopping the clear from occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makePoints() {
      var lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3;

      //some calculations  for coordinates go here

      //create a line object
      var polyline = new deCarta.Core.Polyline({
      lineGeometry: [
          new deCarta.Core.Position(lat2, lon2),
          new deCarta.Core.Position(lat1, lon1),
          new deCarta.Core.Position(lat3, lon3)
      ],
      strokeColor: '#000088',
      strokeWidth: 2
      });

      //add to map
      shapeOverlay.addObject(polyline); 
}

for (var i = 0; i < NumberofPoints; i++) {
    // Try to increase this number if lines can't keep up.
    setTimeout(makePoints, 500 * i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the function you are triggering is going return a value, then use it to break a while loop.